# Как ограничить права роли для канала(discord.py)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
from discord.utils import get

overwrite = discord.PermissionOverwrite()
overwrite.send_messages = False
overwrite.read_messages = False

def get_role_id(role_name: str):
  role = get(ctx.guild.roles, name=role_name)
  role_id = role.id
  return role_id

role_id = get_role_id("dps")

await ctx.channel.set_permissions(role_id, overwrite=overwrite)
```

В документации сказано, что я могу вместо `member` использовать `role`, но не знаю как.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы должны использовать объект роли, а не её id. Например:

```
await ctx.channel.set_permissions(client.fetch_role(role_id), overwrite=overwrite)
```

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо за наводку)